# MapReduce to find Social Network influence

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am very new to MapReduce paradigm. I need help in solving a problem. Any pointers / pseudocode will help:

1. Need to count of followers of a person say X , in social Media.
2. find whom all X follows say A,B and find count of the followers of A and B.

Input is list of (y,x) where y follows x.

Here, i can do Step 1 but am unable to chain Mapreduce jobs to find Step 2.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MapReduce](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.824/papers/mapreduce.pdf) paper. It really well explains the programming model. Have a look at the code of [lab 1](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.824/labs/lab-1.html) of MIT 6.824. All you have to do is think of implementing `doMap` and `doReduce` functions for your usecase.